# Need Help with Series Problem (Series Test)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am having difficulty finding if this series converges or diverges:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^{n+1}}{n^{n-1}}$$

I am unsure of which test to use. At first, I thought I should use alternating series test, but I am unable to manipulate the numerator to $(-1)^{n+1}$. I thought I may be able to use root test, but I have no clue how to manipulate the series to do that.

What series test would I use, and how?

Comment: Why did the alternating test failed ? It seems really a great application of it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. For the future, it would be preferable to use MathJax for mathematical expressions. You can [get started here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), and a more complete reference [can be found here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Atmos I was not able to manipulate the numerator so that it can be considered a case of alternating series (I think), which would require the term -2 to be -1.

Comment: Note that $-2 = (-1)(2)$.  Use the laws of exponents.  You make no mention of the ratio test, which seems the best fit for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alternating series test**

Note that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^{n+1}}{n^{n-1}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\underbrace{\frac{2^{n+1}}{n^{n-1}}}_{:=a_n}.$$
By the alternating series test this converges if

1. $a_n>0$: we can easily this is satisfied
2. $a_n$ is monotonic: $a_n$ is decreasing monotonically
3. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$: I will leave this one to you.

**Comparison test**
$$\left\lvert\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^{n+1}}{n^{n-1}}\right\rvert\le\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{2^{n+1}}{n^{n-1}}}\le \underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^{3}\left({\frac{2}{n}}\right)^{n+1}}_{:= A \text{ is finite}}+\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\left({\frac{2}{n}}\right)^{n+1}\le A+\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\left({\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{n+1}.$$
The last series is a geometric series and therefore converges.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: what can you say about $\dfrac{2^{n-1}}{n^{n-1}}$?

Can you show that $\dfrac{2^{n - 1}}{n^{n-1}} \le \dfrac{1}{n^2}$ for $n \ge N$?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow. How would you get to 2^n-1/n^n-1? Also, if you took the limit of n to infinity, that would show that 1/n^2 is greater or equal, right?

Answer (score 0):

Making the problem more general, let$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\qquad \text{with} \qquad a_n=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n^{n-1}}$$
$$\log(a_n)=(n+1)\log(x)-(n-1)\log(n)$$
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=(n-1) \log (n)-n \log (n+1)+\log (x)$$ Using Taylor for large values of $n$
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=\log \left(\frac{x}{ne}\right)+\frac{1}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}=e^{\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)} \sim \frac{x}{ne} \qquad \to~~0$$